# What crystal oscillator for a CH340G?

Tags: oscillator

I think this should be a relatively simple question.

I need to know what would be the best kind of 12Mhz crystal to run with a CH340G driver.

I know barely anything about oscillators, and everything I found made me all the more confused. If anyone knows a simple answer to what crystal is normally used for something like that, I would be very thankful.

Comment: What does the application diagram in the CH340's datasheet say about this? Also look up other schematics using theCH340, there are plenty of these as many Arduino and ESP based boards use the CH340. Then use what they are using there. I advice you to not to try to re-invent the wheel everytime, just copy what others do. Also: a crystal and a crystal ocsillator are different things. A crystal oscillator is a crystal combined with an oscillator circuit. Many ICs including the CH340 already contain the oscillator circuit so only a crystal is needed.

Comment: The [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Other/CH340DS1.PDF) says to use a crystal, not an oscillator.  12MHz.  What other information do you need about the crystal?

Comment: Thank you both! I will look into all of that! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  you use just about any HC49/U or similar 12MHz crystal with a datasheet load capacitance of 12-18pF and the datasheet-recommended 22pF NP0 ceramic capacitors you will be fine. Ones with 6 or 8pF will also likely be fine.

Using extremely small crystals (with low maximum drive levels) may require more analysis.

The effective load capacitance is 22pF/2 + Cstray.

Comment: Thank you! I will do just that!

Comment: So the HC-49SM would most likely be fine, with two 22PF capacitors?

Comment: Probably. Datasheet?

Comment: Here you go, its in here - https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2877048.pdf?_ga=2.100909378.2101819584.1638981158-401727245.1638981158

Comment: XTL-1079 has 30pF load capacitance datasheet spec, which is higher than I suggested. It will probably still work.

Comment: I was looking at the XLT-5050. (It would be better to have SMT for my case) I think it has a 16pF Load capacitance.

Comment: Should be fine.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! And should I still use 22pF capacitors? Or should it be two 30 pF ones? (so it equals roughly 16pF when theres two?)

Comment: I would stick with the 22pF. 11+4pF or 5pF stray is about right.

Comment: Will do! thanks for everything!